# How to perform hyperparameter tuning of LSTM using GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm, hyperparameters, gridsearchcv

I am new to deep learning, and I started implementing hyperparameter tuning for LSTM using GridSearchCV. My dataset contains 15551 rows and 21 columns and all values are of type float. Here is my code:

```
# import libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit, GridSearchCV, train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

# Load and preprocess the dataset
data = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv")  # Replace with the actual path
target_col = 'rn_val'

# Extract the target variable
target = data[target_col].values

#Variables for training
cols = list(data)[1:22]

# Normalize the data
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
data_normalized = scaler.fit_transform(data[cols].astype(float))

# Define the number of time steps and features
n_steps = 7  # Number of time steps to consider
n_features = data_normalized.shape[1]

# Splitting data into train (67%) and temp (33%)
X_train, data_temp, y_train, target_temp = train_test_split(data_normalized, target, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

# Splitting temp into validation (17%) and test (16%)
X_val, X_test, y_val, y_test = train_test_split(data_temp, target_temp, test_size=0.48, random_state=42)

# Define the LSTM network architecture
def create_lstm_model(neurons, optimizer, activation):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(units=neurons, input_shape=(n_steps, n_features)))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation=activation))
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer)
    return model

# define the grid search parameters
param_grid = {'neurons': [8, 16, 32, 64, 128],
              'optimizer': ['SGD', 'RMSprop', 'Adam'],
              'activation':['relu', 'tanh', 'sigmoid', 'linear','swish']}

model = KerasRegressor(build_fn=create_lstm_model, epochs=10, batch_size=16, verbose=0)

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid,cv=3,refit=False, scoring="accuracy", n_jobs = -1)

grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, y_train)

# summarize results
print("Best accuracy of: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, 
                                         grid_result.best_params_))

means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
params = grid_result.cv_results_['params']
for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
    print("%f (%f) with: %r" % (mean, stdev, param))
```

But I am getting the accuracy value as Nan. This is the output I got, as shown in the screenshot. I have selected the input_shape as (n_steps, n_features). Can anybody check my code and correct me for any mistakes I may have made?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem of regression (you are predicting a continuous variable) yet the metric you specified for the `"scoring"` parameter is `"accuracy"`.

This line of code: `grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid,cv=3,refit=False, scoring="accuracy", n_jobs = -1)`.

You need to select a regression metric, see this table below as specified in the documentation:

[image: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter]

Comment: getting the same results while trying with regression parameters.

Comment: What happens if you train without CV? Do you get some non-nan results?

Comment: No still getting same nan values and I noticed one more thing. I am not getting the best parameters, I am getting just first values of each parameter set. ie, 8 from neurons: [8, 16, 32, 64, 128], SGD from optimizer: ['SGD', 'RMSprop', 'Adam'], and relu from activation :['relu', 'tanh', 'sigmoid', 'linear','swish'].

Comment: So you definitely need to change from accuracy but probably you also have some NaN in your data which can cause you this issue

Comment: I checked the nan values using the following code:

# Assuming your ndarray is named "data_array"
# Check for NaN and None values
nan_count = np.count_nonzero(np.isnan(data_normalized))
none_count = np.count_nonzero(data_normalized == None)

# Check for empty values
empty_count = np.count_nonzero(np.empty_like(data_normalized))

print("Number of NaN values:", nan_count)
print("Number of None values:", none_count)
print("Number of empty values:", empty_count)

and got as:
Number of NaN values: 0
Number of None values: 0
Number of empty values: 0

Answer (score 0):

There are some approaches for LSTM models hyperparameter tuning:

1. You can use **Keras Tuner** and for doing this I strongly recommend you read this code on github: [Link](https://kamran-afzali.github.io/posts/2022-02-20/tuner.html)
2. Also you can declare a function and applying search on it and for doing this I provided you with the link of two different approaches which I recommend you to implement instead of using **GreadSearchCV**: [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/code/kamyarazar/stock-price-prediction-lstm-hyperparameter-tuning), [machinelearningmastery](https://machinelearningmastery.com/tune-lstm-hyperparameters-keras-time-series-forecasting/)